# Realistic art VS realist art

Tags: word-choice

At least from what I've seen, opinions diverge on this one, but I want to be sure whether it's possible to call a work of art 'realist' instead of 'realistic'. Sounds to me like something that makes sense, but I'm not a native speaker.

Wikipedia provides this bit:

> When used as an adverb, "realistic" (usually related to visual appearance) distinguishes itself from "realist" art that concerns subject matter.

Answer (score 2):

Realism is a school of art - also known as *Naturalism* -  and the artists and images of this school are "realists". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realism_(arts)#Visual_arts

> When used as an adjective, "**realistic**" (usually related to visual appearance) distinguishes itself from "**realist**" art that concerns subject matter.

**Realistic** is a common adjective with a definition to be found in any dictionary.